# How to suppress CrossTab Row Headers in Crystal Reports 

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have created a crosstab in crytal report, in which it is required to suppress the Row Headers of the Cross Tab,

I tried suppressing the Row-Header object, but by doing it, I still see the empty Row-Header cells.

Edit:

For example, I have Columns: Opening and Closing and Rows as Dates of some Month, So it would look like following in Cross Tab

```
               Opening      Closing
01/10/2010      500           600
02/10/2010      600           700
03/10/2010      700           800
```

So on and so forth. My purpose is to show only the data without the dates (which are Row headers) and without the headers Opening & Closing, which are column headers.

Is there a way to completely suppress Row Headers in CrossTab ??

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: When you say "row headers", do you mean the column headers above each row?

Comment: Hi , I literally mean the Row Headers for each row, which appear at the left most side of a Row in a Cross Tab,

Comment: However, I also look for Suppressing ColumnHeaders, if you have got solution for it plz do let me know.. thx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any version of Crystal Reports I've seen (haven't seen the more recent versions, though), you can't truly suppress the fields.  While you *can* right-click on the field in the crosstab and check the `Suppress` checkbox, you'll still be left with an empty cell.

Furthermore, even if you try to something like overlaying a square drawing object over the column or row header to try and hide it, the crosstab grid lines will *still* show through.

Why would you want to remove the column and row headers, though?  You'd be left with columns and rows without any meaning, unless you were going to add custom headers and rows yourself.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue not too long ago. Here's what I did:

First, I suppressed the row and column headers (which you'll have to do individually for the "Total" text objects as well as the row/column headers objects themselves) as LittleBobbyTables suggests.

[image]

To fix the empty cells, I simply removed the borders. You can do this in the CrossTab Expert by going to the "Customize Style" tab, and then hitting the "Format Grid Lines" button (I'm not sure what versions of CR have this...may be limited to newer versions). Now you can deselect the "Show Gridlines" check box to hide the entire grid. Now there will be no evidence of the row/column headers except for blank white space which you can then overlay with whatever you want.

I found that overlaying a drawing object is unwieldy and usually looks terrible (particularly if your crosstab is going to grow and shrink a lot) and would suggest avoiding this.

Comment: +1 - Better yet, you can turn all the borders around the former row and column headers white; the inner columns will still have gridlines, and will support multiple columns.  This is a good workaround.

Comment: This mostly worked for me. Format Grid Lines exists in v 11.0.0.2495. I de-selected "Draw" for all "Column labels" except for the bottom border.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Cross Tab Expert and ,Customize Style And select desired row and then check Suppress SubTotals in group options.

Answer (score 0):

At first suppress the row by format object and then select suppress.

In order to remove row box first go to cross tab expert then to customize style. then you have to go to format grideline.
then uncheck the draw check box which line you wantt to remove.